# searching for a text file in the folders and return the path

Tags: python, operating-system, filesystems

I want to use `python` to find a `text` file which its name is given inside the folders of my computer and return the path of the file. I know how it should be done with `bash` script but I am wondering how I can use python for it in a fast way?

Comment: Maybe `os.path.walk` ?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk

Comment: @PadraicCunningham beat me by 14 seconds

Comment: @heinst, probably the time it took to get the link, I was too lazy ;)

Comment: Only other *fast* option would be run `locate file` using subprocess if you had to check a large disk, that would obviously depend on  the db having been updated since the file was created

Comment: @PadraicCunningham How does the second option work?

Comment: @Dalek - to be clear, are you asking for the python equivalent of `NAME="foo.txt"; find . -name $NAME -print` ?

Comment: @Robᵩ exactly similar to this command line and faster.

Comment: @Dalek, you would run it using `subprocess.check_output` but obviously it is not a generic solution

Comment: Also what if there is more than one file with the same name?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Doesn't matter! I want to find an approach similar to what Rob mentioned in bash but instead in python.

Comment: @Dalek, you won't find anything in python as fast as what you can do using bash, I think you would be better off using find or locate running a subprocess if possible if you really want a fast approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
import os
import argparse

parse=argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Find some files in some dirs")
parse.add_argument('FILE_OR_DIR', nargs='+')
args = parse.parse_args()

target_dirs = [d for d in args.FILE_OR_DIR if os.path.isdir(d)] or ['.']
target_files = [f for f in args.FILE_OR_DIR if not os.path.isdir(f)]

for d in target_dirs:
    for root, _, files in os.walk(d):
        for file in files:
            if file in target_files:
                print os.path.join(root, file)
```

Comment: it will be slower than `find` command in bash, see benchmarks in [PEP 471 implementation: os.scandir() directory scanning function](http://bugs.python.org/issue22524)

Comment: You are right. Of course it will go slower. Nothing short of `locate` will go faster than `find`.

Comment: you could try to call [`ftw(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) using `ctypes` manually. Or at the very least, use `os.fwalk()` on supported platforms.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I hadn't noticed `os.fwalk`.